# typeinfo, shared libraries and dlopen() without RTLD_GLOBAL

Tags: c++, exception, matlab, shared-libraries, dlopen

I'm having some trouble with exceptions not functioning correctly (or at least, as I would hope; I know there are issues with this) across shared libraries when loaded using *dlopen*. I include some simplified example code here. The actual situation is *myapp*=Matlab, *myext1*=mexglx matlab extension, *mylib* is a shared library of my code between the two extensions (*myext1*, *myext2*)

**mylib.h**

```
struct Foo { Foo(int a); m_a; }
void throwFoo();
```

**mylib.cpp**

```
#include "mylib.h"
Foo::Foo(int a): m_a(a) {}
void throwFoo() { throw Foo(123); }
```

**myext1.cpp**

```
#include "mylib.h" 
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void entrypoint()    
{ 
   try { throwFoo(); } 
   catch (Foo &e) { std::cout << "Caught foo\n"; }
}
```

**myext2.cpp** Identical to myext1.cpp

**myapp.cpp**

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
int main()
{
  void *fh1 = dlopen("./myext1.so",RTLD_LAZY);
  void *fh2 = dlopen("./myext2.so",RTLD_LAZY);
  void *f1  = dlsym(fh1,"entrypoint");
  void *f2  = dlsym(fh2,"entrypoint");
  ((void (*)())func1)();  // call myext1 (A)
  ((void (*)())func2)();  // call myext2 (B)
}
```

Compiling this code:

```
g++ mylib.cpp -fPIC  -o libmylib.so -shared
g++ myext1.cpp -fPIC -o myext1.so -shared -L. -lmylib -Wl,-rpath=.
g++ myext2.cpp -fPIC -o myext2.so -shared -L. -lmylib -Wl,-rpath=. 
g++ myapp.cpp -fPIC -o myapp -ldl
```

The call to *entrypoint()* at **A** works as expected, with *throwFoo()* throwing the exception and *entrypoint()* catching it. The call at **B** however fails to catch the exception. Adding more diagnostic code shows that the typeinfo for the *Foo* class differs in the two extensions. Changing the order of the two *dlopen* calls makes no difference, the second loaded extension fails.

I know I can fix this by using **RTLD_GLOBAL** as an additional flag for *dlopen*, but the application (Matlab) using dlopen is out of my control. Is there anything I can do with *mylib* or *myext1*, *myext2* to fix this problem?

I have to avoid using LD flags for runtime (since I cannot control the users running the Matlab binary). Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

A simple work-around is to have your library `dlopen` itself with the `RTLD_GLOBAL` flag on the first use. This will override the previous open with `RTLD_LOCAL` and put everything in the global symbol namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Rule 62 in "C++ Coding Standards" by Alexandrescu & Sutter:

"62. Don’t allow exceptions to propagate across module boundaries."

Although it can work when you do it carefully, for true portable and reusable code, this cannot be done. I would say it is a pretty common general rule when programming shared libraries or DLLs, do not propagate exceptions across module boundaries. Just use a C-style interface, return error codes, and do everything inside an exported function inside a `try { } catch(...) { };` block. Also, the RTTI is not shared across modules, so don't expect Foo to have the same typeinfo in different modules.

Comment: From the summary of Rule 62: "Don't allow exceptions to propagate between two pieces of code **unless** you control the compiler and compiler options used to build both sides".  The exceptions I'm propagating above are between _mylib_ and _myext1_ or _myext1_, all of which I have full control over. I very much appreciate that leaking them out into _myapp_ would be a *bad* thing, but I was hoping that there is a way I could use a common exception in my codebase that consists of a number of shared libraries.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there anything I can do with mylib or myext1, myext2 to fix this
>   problem?

As an alternative to using RTLD_GLOBAL you can simply use the enviroment variable `LD_PRELOAD` when you run your application in order to fix your problem. You don't have to recompile anything:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libmylib.so ./myapp
```